# bitshifting unsigned char and unsigned long long gone wrong

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, x86-64

This is a function I (want to) use to decode numbers out of unsigned char[] buffers for networking.

```
inline unsigned long long getULongLongLongInt(const unsigned char* buffer)
{
    unsigned long long number= (buffer[0] << 56);
    number|= (buffer[1] << 48);
    number|= (buffer[2] << 40);
    number|= (buffer[3] << 32);
    number|= (buffer[4] << 24);
    number|= (buffer[5] << 16);
    number|= (buffer[6] << 8);
    number|= buffer[7];
    return number;
}
```

I'm getting warning C4293 '<<': shift count negative or too big, undefined behaviour" four times for the most upper bitshifts;
Is this a warning I can safely ignore because the compiler doesn't recognise I'm using an unsigned 64 bit int? I presume it isn't. But then how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't ignore it. The operand `buffer[i]` is of type `unsigned char`, which is probably promoted to `int` (and if not `int`, then `unsigned int`). If 56 is greater than or equal to the bit width of `int`, then the shift is UB.

You need to write `static_cast<unsigned long long>(buffer[0]) << 56` and so on, so the operand will be at least 64 bits long *before* the shift.

Comment: static casts are supposedly better than regular casts in this case, I presume.

Comment: @blipman17 That's a matter of opinion, but many people recommend avoiding C-style casts in C++, while few would find any fault with using the C++-style cast even if they prefer the C-style cast.

Comment: can't make it work with your proposed edits. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

When used in an expression, `unsigned char` values are promoted to `int`s. Attempting to shift an `int` by 56 bits will, obviously, not be very productive.

You have to be more explicit:

```
 unsigned long long number= ((unsigned long long)buffer[0] << 56);
    number|= ((unsigned long long)buffer[1] << 48);
```

... and so on. You have to force a conversion to `unsigned long long` before the shift operation takes place.

Comment: Promotion of numbers on bitshifting. What is the thought about this behaviour? When would that be usefull?

Comment: It would be useful when you need to get the correct result.

Comment: Yeah but why not automatically cast it to the type that it'll be interacting with? in this case unsigned long long? to "just" cast it to an (unsigned) int sounds like a mistake to me.

Comment: Because it is not "interacting" with an `unsigned long long`. The other value used by the `<<` operator is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to explicitly state intent and let the compiler's optimiser work its magic:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

template<class Unsigned,
std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<Unsigned>::value>* = nullptr
  >
inline Unsigned decode_int_msb(const unsigned char* buffer)
{
  //
  // some helpful types and constants
  //

  using type = Unsigned;
  static constexpr auto bytes = sizeof(type);
  static constexpr auto bits = bytes * 8;

  //
  // a helpful local function
  //

  auto byte = [buffer](auto i) {
    return type(buffer[i]) << bits - ((i+1) * 8);
  };

  //
  // simplified algorithm here
  //

  type acc = 0;
  for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < bytes ; ++i)
    acc += byte(i);
    return acc;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  // force expansion of some templates

  auto x =  decode_int_msb<unsigned long long>(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(argv[0]));
  auto y =  decode_int_msb<unsigned long>(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(argv[0]));
  auto z =  decode_int_msb<unsigned short>(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(argv[0]));
  return x + y + z;
}
```

example assembler output of the unsigned long long version (when not inlined):

```
unsigned long decode_int_msb<unsigned long, (void*)0>(unsigned char const*):
        movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rdi+1]
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rdi+2]
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi+3]
        mov     rsi, rcx
        sal     rdx, 40
        sal     rsi, 48
        sal     rax, 32
        lea     rcx, [rsi+rdx]
        lea     rdx, [rcx+rax]
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi]
        sal     rax, 56
        add     rax, rdx
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rdi+4]
        sal     rdx, 24
        add     rdx, rax
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi+5]
        sal     rax, 16
        add     rdx, rax
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi+6]
        sal     rax, 8
        add     rax, rdx
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rdi+7]
        add     rax, rdx
        ret
```

Comment: That does sound interresting for sure. I'm not sure I completely understand you as a c++ apprentice, but I'll look at the effective difference for myself later in the day.

Answer (score 0):

change code like this:

```
//unsigned long long number= (buffer[0] << 56);
unsigned long long number= ((buffer[0] << 31) << 25);
```